# Weird PHP within html

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I've written some html code, and once i tried to place some PHP inside it, anything below this sign ?> wouldn't appear!!! I have some pictures and text that wouldn't appear unless I place it above. I'm writing with Bootstrap 2.3 and phpMyAdmin 4.10. all languages. Thank you for your time in advance.

here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/myStyle.css">
<title>OJRA - Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:400px; height:400px; border-radius:5px; background-color:#aaa; margin-left:100px;">
<form action="" method="post" style="margin-left:20px;">
<h6>Username</h6>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your Username">
<h6>Password</h6>
<input type="password" name="usrPassowrd" placeholder="Your password">
<h6>Email</h6>
<input type="email" name="usrEmail" placeholder="Your Email"><br>
<input class = "btn btn-default" type="submit" value = "Register">
</form> 

</div>
<div style="width:400px; height:400px; border-radius:5px; background-color:#aaa; margin-left:100px;">
<form action="" method="post" style="margin-left:20px;">
<h6>Username:</h6> <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your username">
<h6>Password:</h6> <input type="password" name="usrPassowrd" placeholder="Your password">      
<input class = "btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Sign in">    
</form>
<?php
define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require 'connect.php';


$username = $_POST['username'];
if($username == "")
{
die("cannot go empty");
header("location:index.php");
exit;
}
$password = $_POST['usrPassword'];
$email = $_POST['usrEmail'];

$query = "insert into tz_members values('$username', '$password', '$email')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


?>
</div>
<img src="sexymotivation.jpg" style="margin-top:-800px; margin-right:10px;" class="pull-right">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you running this on a local machine, or via WWW?

Comment: "sexymotivation.jpg" lol

Comment: That's because something is causing your script to fail. What's the error in your error log?

Comment: And also learn a few things about SQL Injection before making another query...

Comment: `die("cannot go empty");
header("location:index.php");
exit;` hm... Your header won't do anything, cuz it `DIE()'d`

Comment: What I suspect is going on is, because you've got your entire code inside one big clump, and that if certain conditions aren't met... it's still wants to keep going. Now, I suggest that you put a conditional statement wrapped around your PHP.... such `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // PHP }` then add this to your submit button `name="submit"` --- I also suggest you split up your form and your PHP/SQL altogether and make it submit to another page instead, with the same conditional statement I've already outlined.

Comment: I think we would all appreciate a link to sexymotivation.jpg so we can see what that is ;)

Comment: You also have a typo `name="usrPassowrd"` <= change that to => `name="usrPassword"`

Comment: in 2 places actually. ^-----

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things have already been outlined (as answers) that do make sense, however I spotted a few typos in your inputs that will prevent your form from working, plus a few other points.

Here are a few of my recommendations:

First, this (in 2 instances) has a typo in it `name="usrPassowrd"` which should read as `name="usrPassword"` to go with your existing `$password = $_POST['usrPassword'];`

As I stated in my original comments:

**Comment #1:** `die("cannot go empty"); header("location:index.php"); exit;` Your header won't do anything, because it `DIE()'d` and that will cease to go any further.

**Comment #2:** What I suspect is going on is, because you've got your entire code inside one big clump, and that if certain conditions aren't met... it still wants to keep going. Now, I suggest that you put a conditional statement wrapped around your PHP....

such as `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // PHP }` then add this to your submit button `name="submit"` --- I also suggest you split up your form and your PHP/SQL altogether and make it submit to another page instead, with the same conditional statement I've already outlined.

If you absolutely want to execute everything in one page, try the following:

**Note:** I borrowed the `img src` from [**user3009875's**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20694163/1415724) answer also.

(Rewrite)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/myStyle.css">
<title>OJRA - Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:400px; height:400px; border-radius:5px; background-color:#aaa; margin-left:100px;">
<form action="" method="post" style="margin-left:20px;">
<h6>Username</h6>
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your Username">
<h6>Password</h6>
<input type="password" name="usrPassword" placeholder="Your password">
<h6>Email</h6>
<input type="email" name="usrEmail" placeholder="Your Email"><br>
<input class = "btn btn-default" type="submit" value = "Register">
</form> 

</div>
<div style="width:400px; height:400px; border-radius:5px; background-color:#aaa; margin-left:100px;">
<form action="" method="post" style="margin-left:20px;">
<h6>Username:</h6> <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Your username">
<h6>Password:</h6> <input type="password" name="usrPassword" placeholder="Your password">      
<input class = "btn btn-default" name="submit" type="submit" value="Sign in">    
</form>

<?php
// this below, will prevent a premature execution of code
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require 'connect.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
if($username == "")
{
die("cannot go empty");
// header("location:index.php"); // commented out
exit;
}
$password = $_POST['usrPassword'];
$email = $_POST['usrEmail'];

$query = "insert into tz_members values('$username', '$password', '$email')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

} // end brace for if(isset($_POST['submit']))

?>
</div>
<!-- commented out original img src -->
<!--
<img src="sexymotivation.jpg" style="margin-top:-800px; margin-right:10px;" class="pull-right">
-->

<!-- new img src by user3009875 in an answer given -->
<img src="sexymotivation.jpg" style="margin-top:100px; margin-right:10px;" class="pull-right">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `header()` there to perform a redirection because you've already outputted some HTML and PHP has flushed HTTP headers.

The reason that `<img>` disappeared is probably that you called `die()`. This function terminates the whole page at once.

If you see **cannot go empty**, you should check the form to make sure you posted `username` field. If you see some error message about MYSQL, it is `mysql_query($query)` that fails.

By the way, your code has a **SQL Injection** problem.

Answer (score 0):

At this point:

```
die("cannot go empty");
```

you stop the script. The following PHP code will not be executed and the HTML will not be sent to the user.

Comment: You're right! the minute i switched it, the picture was up. thank you

Answer (score 0):

IT doesn't load below ?> because script fails. This is common behaviour when there is a bug.

Check `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` on linux (terminal)

Check `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log` on max (terminal)

windows -> I have no idea... somewhere in `C:\\`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that there is an error when executing your PHP code, that would prevent it from going through the rest of the file.

Using your browser's Developer Tools, check the contents of the HTML that was returned, it's possible that the last line could be an error message. If you have erorr_reporting off then it would write to your error log only.

`/var/log/apache2/error.log` is a common location for the error log file if you are using Apache on a Linux machine.

As a side note, that code you have is very dangerous, do not use data sent from the client directly in a SQL statement, you need to sanitize otherwise you make your web app vulnerable to SQL injection.

Consider using a prepared statement
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
<img src="sexymotivation.jpg" style="margin-top:100px; margin-right:10px;" class="pull-right">
```

I think setting the `top margin` to **-800px** will cause it to disappear from the screen.

Also, make sure your image is of `.jpg`.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think this answer needs some context with it. Why should OP try this? What exactly is different and why would changing it to this make a difference?

Comment: actually this could be true.

Comment: @salivan Absolutely, this could very well be the case, I just felt that someone who wouldn't recognize that the negative margin was the issue would probably have a hard time understanding just a random snippet of code without any explanation. Either way, the answer has been updated now so it's all good!